# Executing a part of code from amazon EC2 cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-ec2

I am having a big cloud formation template and for testing i need to run a part of code from the template and not the complete template.

So for example i need to run only rename block.

```
"Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
 "Metadata" : {
     "AWS::CloudFormation::Init" : {
         "configSets" : {
             "config" : [
                 "rename"
             ]
         },

         "rename"     : {
             "commands" : {
                 "1-execute-powershell-script-RenameComputer" : {
                     "command" : {
                         "Fn::Join" : [
                             "",
                             [
                                 "powershell.exe -Command Rename-Computer -NewName ",
                                 {
                                     "Ref" : "Node1"
                                 },
                                 " -Restart"
                             ]
                         ]
                     },
                     "waitAfterCompletion" : "forever"
                 }
             }
         },
```

Any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Cut and paste the parts you need into a smaller template and execute that as a new stack.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Let me try it out.